# iOS : Paypal Error We’re sorry Things don’t appear to be working at the moment

Tags: ios, swift3, paypal-sandbox, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I implemented checkout flow and I am getting below error

[image: ios emulator screen shot]

**Code :**

```
func startCheckout() {
        // Example: Initialize BTAPIClient, if you haven't already
        braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: clientToken)!
        let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient: braintreeClient)
        payPalDriver.viewControllerPresentingDelegate = self
        payPalDriver.appSwitchDelegate = self // Optional

        // Specify the transaction amount here. "2.32" is used in this example.
        let request = BTPayPalRequest(amount: "2.32")
        request.currencyCode = "USD" // Optional; see BTPayPalRequest.h for more options

        payPalDriver.requestOneTimePayment(request) { (tokenizedPayPalAccount, error) in
            if let tokenizedPayPalAccount = tokenizedPayPalAccount {
                print("Got a nonce: \(tokenizedPayPalAccount.nonce)")

                // Access additional information
                let email = tokenizedPayPalAccount.email
                let firstName = tokenizedPayPalAccount.firstName
                let lastName = tokenizedPayPalAccount.lastName
                let phone = tokenizedPayPalAccount.phone

                // See BTPostalAddress.h for details
                let billingAddress = tokenizedPayPalAccount.billingAddress
                let shippingAddress = tokenizedPayPalAccount.shippingAddress
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error here")
                // Handle error here...
            } else {
                print("Buyer cancelled the payment")
                // Buyer canceled payment approval
            }
        }
    }
```

I following this documentation [link](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/checkout-with-paypal/ios/v4)

Comment: Hi, Did you integrate PayPal successfully? I can have PayPal login screen but after login it shows return to merchant. What is wrong here? It is not showing amount to pay. Please help me with flow.

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason for this issue is because of configuration in paypal.

You can check your configuration in below link 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/

This link is for woo-commerce but will help you in your account configuration.